# How to manually change the returned HTTP code and the message

Tags: php, restler

I like to have messages that are different than the standard returned by RestException class.

For example HTTP code 400 with custom message:

```
return array ('code'=>400, 'result'=>"Fail", 'reason'=>"Bad meta tag: $meta");
```

Is this possible with the latest version of the framework?

Answer (score 0):

You want to have custom HTTP response message. This might help.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: I guess Restler framework over write the header, cause it is still 200 even after placing `http_response_code(400);`